# How to remove whitespaces from the beginning and end of loop phrase

Tags: php

i need to remove whitespaces from the beginning and end of loop phrase

All words come from an loop, and look like this: " Hello all people "

I'm using the code -

```
$appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();
foreach ($appliedFilters as $item) {
        if ($item->getFilter()->getRequestVar() == 'b_car' || 'c_model' || 'd_year') {
            $n_str = string.replace("\"", "", $item->getLabel()));
                   echo $n_str;
                    }
                    }
```

This code returns "Helloallpeople"

But i need "Hello all people"

Please help!

**UPDATED**

```
var_dump($item->getLabel()); returns string(7) "Hello " string(8) "all " string(5) "People "
```

Comment: this isn't an array.  you might find what you need with trim()

Comment: No, tags - just example.

Comment: Use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) instead of str_replace

Comment: "All words come from an array, and look like this:" - That doesn't look like an array. Which part of that comes from the array? Each word? The whole sentence?

Comment: Replace this line $n_str = string.replace("\"", "", $item->getLabel())); to $n_str = trim($item->getLabel()); and check!

Comment: `$n_str = trim($item->getLabel());` it returns "Helloallpeople"

Comment: you need to investigate this method $item->getLabel() ...Content is coming from there like this "Helloallpeople"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Regx like the following:

```
$returnValue = preg_replace("/>\s+(.*)\s+</", '>$1<', '<a> Hello all people <a/>');
```

I am keeping the old answer for reference.
But if you simply want to remove leading and trailing spaces; use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

**Update:**

If you want to trim each and every element of an array; you can map trim function to it.
Then you can also implode the array to a string.

```
<?php
$str = array(" Hello all  ", " Hello all people ", "  all people ", " Hello people ");
$n_str = array_map("trim",$str);
var_dump($n_str);
echo implode(" ",$n_str);
?>
```

**Update 2:**

Ok I got it; It's not an array. It's a loop. 
Every time $item->getLabel() returns just a string. it's not an array.
Following should help you.

```
$appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();
$result = "";
foreach ($appliedFilters as $item) {
        if ($item->getFilter()->getRequestVar() == 'b_car' || 'c_model' || 'd_year') {
            $result .= " ".trim($item->getLabel());
        }
}
echo trim($result);
```

Comment: All words comes from array `$item->getLabel()`

Comment: What does $item->getLabel() exactly returns? 
Is it a array like: "Hello", "all", "people" or set of lines like " Hello all people "

Comment: `var_dump($item->getLabel());` returns `string(7) "Hello " string(8) "all " string(5) "People "`

Comment: $n_str = implode(" ",array_map("trim",$item->getLabel()));

Comment: Updated ver returns "Helloallpeople"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$words = $item->getLabel(); //array(" Hello", "all ", "people "); 
echo trim(preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", implode($words, " ")));

// Output: Hello all people
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/OKjstHbC)

Comment: You're right, it doesn't return anything, it echos "Hello all people". [**See demo**](http://codepad.org/OKjstHbC). Up to you to implement it into your system.

Comment: `$words = array($item->getLabel());
                 echo trim(preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", implode($words, " ")));` returns "Helloallpeople"